# Divide dataframe in different bins based on condition

Tags: pandas

i have a pandas dataframe

```
id  no_of_rows
1  2689
2  1515
3  3826
4  814
5  1650
6  2292
7  1867
8  2096
9  1618
10  923
11  766
12  191
```

i want to divide id's into 5 different bins based on their no. of rows,
such that every bin has approx(equal no of rows)
and assign it as a new column `bin`

One approach i thought was

```
df.no_of_rows.sum() = 20247
div_factor = 20247//5 == 4049
```

if we add 1st and 2nd row its sum = 2689+1515 = 4204 > div_factor.
Therefore assign bin = 1 where id = 1.
Now look for the next ones

```
id  no_of_rows  bin
1  2689          1
2  1515          2
3  3826          3
4  814           4
5  1650          4
6  2292          5
7  1867
8  2096
9  1618
10  923
11  766
12  191
```

But this method proved wrong.

Is there a way to have 5 bins such that every bin has good amount of stores(approximately equal)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an approach based on percentiles.

```
n_bins = 5
dfa = df.sort_values(by='no_of_rows').cumsum()
df['bin'] = dfa.no_of_rows.apply(lambda x: int(n_bins*x/dfa.no_of_rows.max()))
```

And then you can check with

```
df.groupby('bin').sum()
```

The more records you have the more fair it will be in terms of dispersion.